# How to call procedure for each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Microsoft SQL Server R2 2008. And i see it first time in my life.
I have sql procedure:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @Id uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @Segment_ID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @SDate datetime
DECLARE @EDate datetime
DECLARE @withBig bit
DECLARE @withKm bit
DECLARE @withGeo bit
DECLARE @withDescr bit

-- TODO: задайте здесь значения параметров.

EXECUTE @RC = [Request_BusStation] 
   @Id
  ,@Segment_ID
  ,@SDate
  ,@EDate
  ,@withBig
  ,@withKm
  ,@withGeo
  ,@withDescr
GO
```

How i understand its just calling of procedure not thetself. But procedure too bit to copy it here. 
AND have a table:

```
   CREATE TABLE [BusStation](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Segment_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Dist] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
[Kod_Spr012] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Square] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
[OperationStartDate] [date] NULL,
[BallanceCost] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
[DepreciatedCost] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
[ChargesNorm] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
[DocumentName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[DocumentNum] [varchar](100) NULL,
[DocumentDate] [date] NULL,
[Authority] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Kod_Spr091] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[HasWaysideStop] [bit] NOT NULL,
[HasLanding] [bit] NOT NULL,
[HasSpeedTransitArea] [bit] NOT NULL,
[LenSpeedTransitArea] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
[YearBuilt] [smallint] NULL,
[YearMajorOverhaul] [smallint] NULL,
[Kod_Spr019] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[TechCond] [varbinary](max) NULL,
[LandCont] [varbinary](max) NULL,
[LandContDate] [date] NULL,
[LandContStartDate] [date] NULL,
[LandContEndDate] [date] NULL,
[Kod_Spr120] [smallint] NULL,
[E_Date_Begin] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[E_Date_End] [datetime] NULL,
[E_Date_Stop] [datetime] NULL,
```

Now i want to call this procedure for each row of table.
Its possible?

Comment: I think you'll need to declare a Cursor (as much as I hate them).  Loop through all your records and call the SP.

Comment: @ sgeddes: Thank you. But can you give me example?

Comment: If you are not performing `insert/update/delete` inside your procedure, you could do it with a `function` without using cursors. Can you show your procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the only way I would know how to do that is using a `CURSOR`.  Here is some sample code (untested of course):

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @Segment_ID uniqueidentifier

DECLARE @getAccountID CURSOR
SET @BusStationCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT Id, Segment_ID --(etc: all the fields you need)
FROM BusStation

OPEN @BusStationCursor
FETCH NEXT    FROM @BusStationCursor INTO @ID, @Segment_ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--CALL YOUR SP HERE
PRINT @ID 
PRINT @Segment_ID

FETCH NEXT    FROM @BusStationCursor INTO @ID, @Segment_ID
END
CLOSE @BusStationCursor
DEALLOCATE @BusStationCursor
```

This should help as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you) . But i have last question i can create cursor in calling procedure( in code snippet what i pastle in my question) or i gonna do it in procedure?

Comment: You can create it in your above code -- change where I have @PRINT... to your Execute statement.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry i was really stupid. Your code work really nice. What i want.^__^

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a cursor that selects all the rows in the table and iteratively calls the stored procedure.

I would suggest that you may have a design issue before going down that route though. If the stored procedure needs to be called for every row in the table, you may be able to write a stored procedure that simply does what your current sp does to all the rows instead of a single row operation.

You have not provided what the sp is doing so I can only speculate here.